# How can I find the number of solutions to $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n = N;\; 1\leq a_i \leq K$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I know stars and bars theorem. I can solve $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n = N;\; 1\leq a_i \leq K$, if $a_i \geq K$. Then we can set $a_i' = a_i - K$ and convert that to $$a_1' + a_2' + a_3' + \cdots a_n' = N + Kn;\; a_i \geq 0$$
Then the number of solutions will be $\dbinom{N+Kn + n - 1}{n-1}$.

But how can I handle this when $a_i \leq K$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570989/sequences-of-integers-0-a-1-leq-a-2-leq-ldots-leq-a-n-such-that-a-kk-for-ev?rq=1 
Relative question.

Comment: @RezwanArefin That question was also mine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extended stars-and-bars problem(where the upper limit of the variable is bounded)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded)

Answer (score 1):

It is the coefficient of $X^N$ in the expression $\prod_{i=1}^N(1+X+X^2+\dots +X^K)$

Comment: How can I find that! :(

Comment: Using the multinomial theorem :P

Comment: I don't know that :( Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: I don't think there's a closed form expression.

Comment: Is the equation equivalent to  ${(1+x+x^2 + \cdots x^k)}^n$

Comment: @0123456789101112 Yes, it is.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the 3 problems below:

**Problem A:** $$x_1+\cdots+x_n=N\\s.t.~x_i\geq0~\forall i, ~\text{and}~x_1\geq k+1$$
**Problem B:** $$x_1+\cdots+x_n=N\\s.t.~x_i\geq0~\forall i, ~\text{and}~x_j\geq k+1~\text{for some}~j$$
**Problem C:** $$x_1+\cdots+x_n=N\\s.t.~x_i\geq0~\forall i$$
**Problem D:** $$x_1+\cdots+x_n=N\\s.t.~0\leq x_i\leq k~\forall i$$
**Problem E:** $$x_1+\cdots+x_n=N-k-1\\s.t.~x_i\geq0~\forall i$$
Let $N_a.N_b,N_c,N_d$ be the number of solutions to Problem A,B,C,D respectively. Then $$N_d=N_c-N_b$$$$N_b=n!\times N_a$$$$N_a=N_e$$